# Screensaver on only one monito in dual monitor setup

Tags: windows-7, display, multiple-monitors, screensaver

I have a dual monitor setup on Windows 7 with monitor 1 and monitor 2. I have a very specific need.

When monitor 2 is unused for 3 minutes I want monitor 2 to display a screensaver and I still want to be able to work with monitor 1. I want monitor 2 to be inactive and monitor 1 to be active at the same time. I want this to be done automatically without any human intervention.

I have tried UltraMon and DisplayFusion without success.

Answer (score -1):

Hit the power button on monitor 2 after three minutes. Hit it again when you want it back.

Comment: I want it to run automatically without human intervention as monitor 2 is not within reach. This is not the correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

Screen savers only activate when the keyboard has been idle for a specified period.  Rather than the screensaver, why not set Monitor 2 so that it rotates its wallpaper at set intervals?